# Why is a vector a rank-1 tensor?

Tags: tensor-calculus, vectors, definition

I learned that a tensor is a linear map from some number of vectors to the real numbers.

For example, $t(\vec{u},\vec{v})=\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}$ is a rank-2 tensor as it takes 2 vectors as arguments and combines them into a real number.

I then read that a rank-1 tensor is a vector. How is that possible? If the rank-1 tensor is a vector, it will mean $t({\vec u})=\vec{u}$, but $\vec{u}$ is not a real number.

Comment: "If the rank-1 tensor is a vector, it will mean $t({\vec u})=\vec{u}$" How so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An $(r,s)$-tensor maps $r$ dual vectors and $s$ vectors to some field (e.g. $\mathbb{R}$). The rank of a tensor is defined as $r+s$. One can interpret a vector $v$ as $(1,0)$-tensor, mapping a dual vector $w$ to the number $w(v)$.